# Regarding PDFSharp with Migra-Doc in .netcore 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to import existing pdf using PdfSharp and writing the same pdf to another pdf doc.But,I am getting error while adding page to the new pdf doc.Can someone suggest that what I am doing wrong.Below id the code snippet that I am using.

```
  var fullPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        PdfDocument PDFDoc = PdfReader.Open(fullPath + "\\PrePrintedHCFA_1500.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
        PdfDocument PDFNewDoc = new PdfDocument();
        PDFNewDoc.AddPage(PDFDoc.Pages[0]);//This line gives error
        PdfPage page = PDFNewDoc.Pages[0];
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
```

Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that PDF sharp fully supports .net core. You could have a look at PDFsharp (PDF Core) [here](http://www.pdfsharp.net/(X(1)S(k5gj5m55vo1wwiikasrj3u2z))/NuGetPackage_PDFsharp.ashx), which "does not rely on graphics libraries and can be used on (almost) any platform." From this [issue](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/issues/6), it appears to be still in progress.  You could also look at this [fork](https://github.com/YetaWF/PDFsharp-.netcoreapp2.0), build it yourself and see if it works for you.  It's intended as a stop gap until PDF Sharp fully supports .net core.